# How to sort a table containing csv file data

Tags: php, usort

I have to sort the file data in a table depending on how the user chooses it to be sorted (only options are ascending and descending)

Here is my code for it:

```
if($submit=="Display"){
    if ($headings=="0"){echo "<h2>Error</h2>";}
    elseif ($search==""){echo "<h2>Error</h2>";}
    else {

        if($headings==$headings_array[0])
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            $f = fopen("data.csv", "r");

            while ($line = fgetcsv($f)){
            echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    echo "<td><center>".$cell."</center></td>";
                }
            echo "<tr>";
            }   
            fclose($f);

            function my_sort($a, $b){
                if ($a == $b) return 0;
                return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
                }

            $arr = $cell;

            usort($arr, "my_sort");

            print_r ($arr);
            echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

But it's not sorting. Can someone spot what's wrong with it? And if you have a more efficient way of doing this, please let me know as I have 15 `headings` and it would be a pain to do `if statements` for each of those headings.

**To be clear, here is what I have to do:**

For each sort field (which are the headings) that the user chooses, I have to arrange the display according to that heading

i.e `if($headings==$headings_array[0])`

`$headings_array[0]` is equal to `Names` therefore, the table should display the values in alphabetical (or reverse alphabetical) order of `Names`

**Extra info:**

`$headings` is the name of the select box
`$headings_array` is the array values for the select box
`$search` is the radio buttons containing whether the table should be sorted as ascending or descending
*PHP only*

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should really try to separate out the display logic (how to write out the html) from the application logic (reading the CSV and sorting it). There are various frameworks that enforce this (usually they call it MVC), but in general your life will be happier if you first get your data the way you want it before you print anything to the screen.

Comment: @Eli Alright, I guess I'll try to sort everything without the table first and add that once everything works, thanks for your time!

Comment: what you should do is store the data in a database and let the database sort the records for you...

Comment: @dqhendricks I would but I'm not allowed to use one for this project

Answer (score 0):

I think your sort function is wrong. It's doing the same thing as sort() or rsort() would do.

usort simply compares two array elements and determines if they need to be swapped based on the value you return. Your sending in $a and $b, which should be csv lines. Then you compare the indexes that you need to and swap the lines accordingly.

You need to have it sort by the array index given by heading. maybe try something like this:

```
global $headings;

...
$arrayToBeSorted = array();

// send in an array of lines
while ($line = fgetcsv($f)){
    $arrayToBeSorted[] = $line;
}

usort($arrayToBeSorted, 'my_sort');

function my_sort($lineA, $lineB){
    // set this to the column that needs to be sorted
    global $headings;

    $linePartsA = explode(',' $lineA);
    $linePartsB = explode(',' $lineB);
    if ($linePartsA[$headings] == $linePartsB[$heading) return 0;
        return ($linePartsA[$headings] > $linePartsB[$heading]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to refactor a little, Eli was right about seperating the html from the program logic. You'll probably want to build $arrayToBeSorted in the while loop where you read in the file. You'll have to be sure that the value in $headings matches the indexes in $linePartsA&B.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use php only . I used jquery table sorter which is very efficient .here is the link [table sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: I'm aware that php isn't the most efficient way but unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use anything else but php for this project